# Solution to a system of ODE:s

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Consider a system of linear ODE:s:

$$x'(t)=Ax(t)+C$$

Here $A$ and $C$ are coefficient matrices. If $C=0$, the solution is $x(t)=\exp(Ax(t))x(0)$, where $\exp$ represents the matrix exponential. Can we write a similar solution for a general $C$?

Comment: @Moo Thanks will check these. They seem to consider $x'(t)=Ax(t)+f(t)$. I was thinking if there is some simple matrix form solution for the case $f(t)$ is constant. Such a simple solution exists at least for $C=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the matrix exponential as integrating factor you get
$$
(e^{-At}x(t))'=e^{-At}C
$$
which can be integrated to (at first only for regular $A$, but in the end for all $A$)
$$
e^{-At}x(t)-x(0)=-A^{-1}(e^{-At}-I)C
\implies
x(t)=e^{At}x(0)+t\phi_1(At)C
$$
where $\phi_1$ is the matrix version of the function $\phi_1(z)=\frac{e^z-1}{z}$, continued with $\phi_1(0)=1$ as per its power series. Note that $\phi_1$, despite its singular definition, is an analytical or entire function, similar to the exponential.

These modified exponentials, matrix phi functions or whatever name they got in-between, $\phi_2(z)=\frac{e^z-1-z}{z^2}$ etc. occur also in exponential Runge-Kutta methods, thus they are also implemented in good numerical linear algebra libraries along the matrix exponential.

Comment: Because $\phi_1(tA)=(tA)^{-1}(e^{tA}-I)$, and there is no $t$ in the denominator after integration.

Comment: I got it thanks. but then shouldnt it be $\phi (-At)$ ? and $e^{At}$ seems missing

Comment: Not after you undo the integrating factor.

Comment: $e^{-At}x(t)-x(0)=-A^{-1}(e^{-At}-I)C \implies -e^{At}x(0)+x(t)=-e^{At}A^{-1}(e^{-At}-I)C$

Comment: Yes. And everything that is a polynomial or series in $A$ commutes with $A$.

Comment: Thank you so much Lutz for the explanation looks clearer now +1

Comment: What would be the best way to evaluate $\phi_1$ in Matlab? It has the expm command for matrix exponential.

Comment: Somewhere else in the context of phi functions the `funm` function was mentioned. It extends analytic scalar functions to matrix functions. I thought I had seen there or in scipy a method specific for phi functions, but can not find that again.